# How can I call a simulink block from matlab editor?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm beginner at simulink block. Actually I'm working at time delayed system. I have a simulink block to apply a time varying delay in a signal.

I'm using matlab editor with for loop to define my variables with different values. These variables are the input of the simulink block. I used simto workspace as output. I want to use this output in matlab editor in the same forloop as scalar. 
How can I modify the dimension  of output ?
[image]

```
for t=0:0.001:5
   v1=...
   sim(v1delay.slx');
   z=v1delay*A;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely inappropriate for what you are trying to achieve.  You should read [How Simulink Works](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/introduction_f7-5734.html) (and the pages linked off that page) to get a better understanding of what it is and how to use it.

The `sim` function will simulate your model from the start time to end time (that you have specified in your model, ***not*** your variable `t`)  You should not be using it in a loop where you (think you) are incrementing time yourself - the Simulink `solver` does that for you.

The way you have set up the `From Workspace` block requires you to define, in MATLAB, a variable called `t` and another called `v1`, both of which must be column vectors.  (It looks like you also need to define a variable called `tauf`, although it's not clear what that block is so I can't be sure.)

```
t=0:0.001:5
v1=...
```

Specifically note that `t` is used to define the time points at which `v1` changes,  it has nothing to do with the time steps taken by the Simulink solver stepping the model through time.

Then you want to run the simulation,

```
sim('v1delay');
```

This will generate a variable called `v1_delay` in the MATLAB Workspace.  The `To Workspace` block allows this to be one of several different data-types.  Depending on which one you have selected, you will use slightly different functionality to access the actual numeric data to calculate your `z` variable.

```
z=??? % syntax will depend on the data type of v1_delay
```